# Ngb Typehead result with sections

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I want to customize ngb typeahead dropdown.so far managed to create[this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z7c4nf?file=app%2Ftypeahead-template.ts) .when I try to render my list in the template it renders subsection as one item that happens to add a new section button too. I want to achieve something like the below image.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You always can add a "fool" element and use ng-container to give a different aparence. More or less like [your forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z7c4nf-onpkoc?file=app%2Ftypeahead-template.ts)

In search we add an element

```
search = (text$: Observable<string>) => {
    const debouncedText$ = text$.pipe(debounceTime(200), distinctUntilChanged());
    const clicksWithClosedPopup$ = this.click$.pipe(
        //see that I change the filter adding this.instance &&
        filter(() => this.instance && !this.instance.isPopupOpen()));
    const inputFocus$ = this.focus$;

    return merge(debouncedText$, inputFocus$, clicksWithClosedPopup$).pipe(
      map((term: string) => (term === '' ? category
        : category.filter(v => v.categoryName.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1))
        .slice(0, 10) //add a new value with categoryId=0
        .concat([{categoryId: 0,categoryName: "Add",subCategoriesList:[]}]))
    );
  }
```

And the template like

```
<ng-template #rt let-r="result" let-t="term">
    <ng-container *ngIf="r.categoryId">
        <li style="color:green">{{r.categoryName}}</li>
        <li *ngFor="let item of r['subCategoriesList']">
            {{item}}
        </li>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngIf="r.categoryId==0">
         <li><button class="btn">Add</button></li>
  </ng-container>
</ng-template>
```